# Play Framework - issues with RequireJS optimizer

Tags: playframework, requirejs, typesafe-activator, requirejs-optimizer, sbt-rjs

I have a [PlayFramework](http://playframework.com) 2.3 project and using [require.js](http://requirejs.org) on the client side.

When I run `activator run` everything works fine (so I'm sure the dependencies of require are ok). But when running `activator start`, some of the dependencies are missing.

In the play documentation ([here](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.6/RequireJS-support)) they say:

> The RequireJS optimizer shouldn’t generally kick-in until it is time
>   to perform a deployment i.e. by running the start, stage or dist
>   tasks.

So the optimizer runs when running `start` and doesn't run when running `run`, and that explains why everything works fine when running `activator run`.

So, Is there is anyway to configure the optimizer or to disable it when running `activator start`?